# python logging handler not appending formatted string to log

Tags: python, logging

I have setup a python logging `RotatingFileHandler` with the `logging` module and created a string formatting config.  Here is my test script:

```
class ExceptionHandler :

    def __init__ ( self ) : 
        self.log = self.setupLog ( "testlog" )

    def setupLog (self, name) :
        log = logging.getLogger(name)

        logging.basicConfig(format="%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(funcName)s %(lineno)d %(message)s")

        #by setting our logger to the DEBUG level (lowest level) we will include all other levels by default
        log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        #setup the rotating file handler to automatically increment the log file name when the max size is reached
        log.addHandler( logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler('%s.log' % name, mode='a', maxBytes=50000, backupCount=5) )

        return log

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    exceptionHandler = ExceptionHandler()
    exceptionHandler.log.log( 20, "Successfully completed script!" )
```

What I'm expecting in my `testlog.log` file is this output; instead this is only being printed to stdout and not my file:

```
INFO 2015-05-06 09:07:55,472 <module> 56 Successfully completed script!
```

And what I'm getting in my file is simply the following without any string formatting:

```
Successfully completed script!
```

Does anyone know what the problem is with my log setup/config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing the correct result on the console because the log is being propogated from your new `Logger` named `testlog` to the root logger which is still writing to the console.  This `Logger` has the correct formatting as set 
by `basicConfig`.

However, your new `Handler` does not inherit that config from `basicConfig()` because, [as the docs say](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig), all it does is

> Does basic configuration for the logging system by creating a StreamHandler with a default Formatter and adding it to the root logger.

You need to [add the formatting to your handler](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#handlers). Something like this:

```
#setup the rotating file handler to automatically increment the log file name when the max size is reached
file_handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler('%s.log' % name, mode='a', maxBytes=50000, backupCount=5)
file_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(fmt="%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(funcName)s %(lineno)d %(message)s"))
log.addHandler(file_handler)
```

**N.B.** If you don't want to pass the messages on to the root logger - add `log.propagate = False` in your `setupLog` function

Comment: Thanks, it looks like both yours and mine would work. I'll give you my points ;)

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue by changing how the formatter gets applied to the logging handler like so:

```
def setupLog (self, name) :
    log = logging.getLogger(name)
    #by setting our logger to the DEBUG level (lowest level) we will include all other levels by default
    log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler('%s.log' % name, mode='a', maxBytes=50000, backupCount=5)

    #logging.basicConfig(format="%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(funcName)s %(lineno)d %(message)s")
    handler.setFormatter( logging.Formatter( "%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(funcName)s %(lineno)d %(message)s" ) )

    #setup the rotating file handler to automatically increment the log file name when the max size is reached
    log.addHandler( handler )

    return log
```

Answer (score -4):

try with the ***logging.basicConfig*** before the **log = logging.getLogger(name)***

```
def setupLog (self, name) :
    logging.basicConfig(format="%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(funcName)s %(lineno)d %(message)s")

    log = logging.getLogger(name)
```